# Difference between "relationship" and "relation"

Tags: writing-style, tech-writing, writing-advice

How can I easily differentiate between when to use "relationship" and "relation". More often than not,  I tend to use "relationship", but would really like to know how these are to be used in writing. Speaking from a general viewpoint, the definition for both of these is almost similar. (this is something I've gathered from a simple Google Search)
When discussing two entities, relationship seems to be an appropriate choice. But there are times when these could be interchangeable.
For e.g., the relation between writing and reality  OR
the relationship between writing and reality. 
So are there are rules or pointers that are to be kept in mind to avoid using these incorrectly?

Comment: What did you find out from dictionaries? In what way specifically were the definitions not clear? Please add the information into your question. Don't reply to me below.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. I've detailed my question a little more so as to clarify what my doubt is.  While the links provided did help, I'm still little confused.